# MySQL table structure for messaging system

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on an instant messaging system which use MySQL.
Current table structure looks like this:

```
id
from_user_id (FK)
to_user_id (FK)
text
date
new
```

I have some problems with it though.

Firstly, I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE to_user_id = (my_id) ORDER BY date desc GROUP BY from_user_id
```

This will return all users who has sent me a message.

Secondly, I save their ID's into an array.

Thirdly, I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE from_user_id = (my_id) AND to_user_id NOT IN (array_of_ids) ORDER BY date desc GROUP BY to_user_id
```

This will return all users who I have sent messages to but they haven't.

This is working great.

Every message that user sends has a field 'new' set to true. This is here because I want to notify the other user (receiver of the message) that he got a new message.

Problem is it appears as new message to the sender too.

Any thoughts on how to fix that or change these two SQLs into a big one?

Comment: "This will return all users who I have sent messages to but they haven't." - you might need to rephrase this.

Comment: Users who I have sent message to, but they haven't sent me any yet.

Comment: i can't understand what you are really trying to do but i think it involves depth. Read < http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/>article for structuring table in this situation

Comment: I need to make a dialog structure I suppose? So the user opens his/her "Message" page and there will be a list of all people who has written him and he has written them too. And when someone messages this user, it will show as "new" message.

Comment: Just maybe not select the new column in the other case but always false?